# How does the motherboard know that the OS is hibernated?

Tags: motherboard, bios, hibernate

Well I recently read that when you hibernate the state is saved to the hard drive.

However this confused me...

When I hibernate my PC (or follow windows' new hybrid booting) and I turn it back on were it usually has HP (or any other OEM) it doesn't show information on entering the BIOS. (*F1 - Setup  ESC - Boot menu...*)

## My Question

How does the motherboard already know that the OS is in a hibernated state if it is from the HD. I believe the HD has not yet been *launched* yet so there could be no HD.

*Hope it made sense*

Comment: Incorrect: during *sleep* the PC is never fully turned off. During *hibernation*, all volatile information is stored to disk. You may unplug the PC, and even remove the battery from a laptop, but when power is restored, the previous Windows state is restored from disk (the information in hiberfil.sys.).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik sleep state saved to rqm; hibernation state saved to HD.

Comment: How do you think the motherboard is involved in the booting of an operating system? The bootloader has that job.

Comment: As soon as windows starts, the bootloader, access the hdd to check it's settings, date and time from the HDD, my guess is that there must be a log file or something created, whenever you put your PC in hibernation mode, which the bootloader access and skips the screen. Although I haven't noticed something like this ever, so I will be trying it now and would answer here the results.

Comment: @Hunter the presence of `hiberfil.sys` in the partition where Windows is installed a dead giveaway of a hibernated state. The Windows bootloader could simply check for the presence of that file and perform some integrity checks and  proceed to load that file into memory.

Comment: But bootloader and the splash screen doesn't have anything related. I doubt it, it couldn't be because of the hibernation.

Comment: I checked my system, and it showed me the splash screen, the buttons too. I don't know, but maybe you have changed fine settings in your BIOS. I was right, the bootloader doesn't have anything to do with the splash screen of the motherboard.

Comment: @RACING121 I recommend reading this excellent article on [the BIOS/MBR boot process](https://neosmart.net/wiki/mbr-boot-process/) written by the guy who created [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). It'll help you understand how a PC boots up.

Comment: @Hunter I am not talking about the bootloader, I am talking about the thing before that.

Comment: @Racing121 the main thing you are asking is why your splash screen doesn't show you the key buttons to press while the windows boots, i.e. the function keys or others for BIOS operations, but that has nothing to do with hibernating the system. The splash screen is linked with BIOS, and BIOS is the first thing that starts up. As the article that referred to, and also BIOS would never know if your PC is hibernated or not. And after that comes the MBR which access the disk0, which tells MBR if the system is hibernated or not, after which the bootloader access the windows partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exact way is implementation-dependent. In general BIOS while booting, based on chipset registers values and content of NVRAM, decide what boot path should be used to wake up platform. Note that while going to [ACPI S4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Global_states) (aka *Hibernate* or *Suspend to Disk*) system indicate it in different way to hardware then S5 (soft power off) or G3 (mechanical power off).

Why vendors prevent entering BIOS setup while waking up from S4 or S3 ?

I see at least 2 reasons:

1. Entering BIOS setup, while waking up from S4, and changing some options may cause unrecoverable system crash.
2. It is very hard to test all conditions that may happen. To cut platform cost vendor prevent entering BIOS while waking up from S4 (I assume same thing is in case of S3, but then additional reason is that OS context is in DRAM).

For example I found that for [Intel 9 Series Chipset Family](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/9-series-chipset-pch-datasheet.html) there is SPL_TYP bit filed in PM1_CNT register that keeps sleep state until reset by RTCRST# signal. So those value will be preserved, CMOS RAM will be cleared ie. by jumper or removing battery.

More about this topic in:

- [ACPI Specification - 16.1 Sleep States](http://www.acpi.info/DOWNLOADS/ACPI_5_Errata%20A.zip)